# Xcode won't compile in kmm project

Tags: xcode, kotlin-multiplatform

/bin/sh -c /Users/bimpos/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iosApp-fmohpbncpclqkmfhfeoxygquosgt/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/shared.build/Script-BEA8885189D408D600647BDC228A6A20.sh

```
            REPO_ROOT="$PODS_TARGET_SRCROOT"
            "$REPO_ROOT/../gradlew" -p "$REPO_ROOT" $KOTLIN_PROJECT_PATH:syncFramework                     -Pkotlin.native.cocoapods.platform=$PLATFORM_NAME                     -Pkotlin.native.cocoapods.archs="$ARCHS"                     -Pkotlin.native.cocoapods.configuration="$CONFIGURATION"
```

env: sh\r: No such file or directory
Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're missing a x64 target on your shared gradle file.
If you go into the Multiplatform Module's gradle file (by default it's called **shared**). **It should look something like this:**

```
kotlin {
     x64()   // for rosetta devices
     arm64()  //arm64 devices
     arm64Simulator()
   
     commonMain{   } // your shared module (default name is commonMain)

     val x64 by getting 
     val arm64 by getting
     val arm64Simulator by getting
     iOSMain(){   // any source sets you write into iOS Main gets added into target folders
        dependsOn(commonMain)
        x64.dependsOn(this)
        arm64.dependsOn(this)
        arm64Simulator.dependsOn(this)
     }

}
```